# NSHTTPURLResponse statusCode is returning zero when it should be 401

Tags: objective-c, iphone, http, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS: How can i receive HTTP 401 instead of -1012 NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912532/ios-how-can-i-receive-http-401-instead-of-1012-nsurlerrorusercancelledauthenti)

Just doing a normal HTTP post with a NSMutableURLRequest and sendSynchronousRequest.  But the NSHTTPURLResponse object I pass in has a statusCode of zero after the call.  I get this error:

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 UserInfo=0x4d3b3c0 "Operation could not be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"

but no status code.  Why?  The status code the server is sending is 401.

Comment: Just to reassure you, it's now 5 years later, and the latest version of XCode still fails miserably with this bug.   At least Apple are consistent...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912532/ios-how-can-i-receive-http-401-instead-of-1012-nsurlerrorusercancelledauthenti/29341651#29341651

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a solution to the problem, but [here is a list of `NSURLErrorDomain` codes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40) of which `-1012` refers to [`NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication), if that helps narrow down the cause.

Comment: Thanks, it seems even though the server sends 401 u cannot check for 401 in your code.  You have to check for NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication instead.  This seems special to 401.  For example 403 works fine.

Comment: Just wondering, is this specific only to the sendSynchronousRequest? Because I am able to get 401s with my async connections.