# Trouble getting a 401 response (unauthorized) from an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, unauthorized, nsurlerrordomain

I have a synchronous method to send out requests that looks like the following:

```
+ (NSString *)sendRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    NSData *responseData = 
 [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request                         
        returningResponse:&response 
           error:&error];

 NSLog(@"response = %@", response);
 NSLog(@"error = %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    NSString *responseString = 
 [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData 
        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseString autorelease];

    NSLog(@"%@: %@", [request HTTPMethod], [request URL]);
    NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [response statusCode]);
    NSLog(@"Content-Type: %@", [[response allHeaderFields] 
                                objectForKey:@"Content-Type"]);
    NSLog(@"Response: %@\n\n", responseString);   

    return responseString;
}
```

For a particular request, I am getting a null response with an error saying "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"

According to the [Foundation constants reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40) this code is NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication which is described as

> Returned when an asynchronous request
>   for authentication is cancelled by the
>   user.
>
> This is typically incurred by clicking
>   a "Cancel" button in a
>   username/password dialog, rather than
>   the user making an attempt to
>   authenticate.

However, I there is no user clicking cancel.  I am simply making a request to retrieve a list of events without being authorized and therefore the 401 I return should produce an unauthorized response, not a null response with a NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication error.  My Rails code that returns this response is the following:

```
def require_auth
    # Return unauthorized if the API call was not made by an authorized user
    unless current_user
      respond_to do |format|
        #format.json { render :text => "Unauthorized", :status => :unauthorized }
        format.json { head :unauthorized }
        format.xml { head :unauthorized }
      end
    end   
end
```

and the output from my Rails log looks like this:

```
Started GET "/events.json" for
127.0.0.1 at Fri Jan 07 10:51:47 -0500 2011   
Processing by EventsController#index as JSON Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to create the correct response?

Answer (score 1):

I'm more of a Rails guy than an iPhone guy, but quick googling (see thread here: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7915337) that NSURLConnection only returns a NSHTTPURLResponse when it's successful (200) and otherwise returns the null response and the behavior you're seeing on a 401.

It looks like this is the nature of the API and you'll need to use something lower level if you want to distinguish between different non-200 status responses.

This other Stackoverflow thread seems to imply the asynchronous version of the API will let you get all of the response codes and data: [iOS: How can i receive HTTP 401 instead of -1012 NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912532/ios-how-can-i-receive-http-401-instead-of-1012-nsurlerrorusercancelledauthentic)