# Failed to fetch current user The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking

I'm getting NSURLErrorDomain error -1012. error in xcode 6.2 , I'm able to get the access token successfully, I tried reseting simulator.. here is the code

```
-(void)getLinkedInData:(LIALinkedInHttpClient*)client
{
    [client getAuthorizationCode:^(NSString *code) {
        [client getAccessToken:code success:^(NSDictionary *accessTokenData) {
            NSLog(@"Access token data: %@",accessTokenData);
            NSString *accessToken = [accessTokenData objectForKey:@"access_token"];
               NSLog(@"Access token: %@",accessToken);
            [client GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *result) {
                NSLog(@"current user %@", result);
            }            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"failed to fetch current user %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }];
        }                   failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Querying accessToken failed %@", error);
        }];
    }                          cancel:^{
        NSLog(@"Authorization was cancelled by user");
    }                         failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Authorization failed ::::%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this'll answer your question, but I've found that when a calling a web service *synchronously*, which returns a 401 "Not authorised" error, iOS will simply return a vague -1012 error.

[iOS: How can i receive HTTP 401 instead of -1012 NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912532/ios-how-can-i-receive-http-401-instead-of-1012-nsurlerrorusercancelledauthenti)

So, try to check whether you're having authentication problems, and tackle the problem from there.